# NextJS: how to Link to new page with current page slugs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I currently have a url like this:

`http://localhost:3000/courses/italian/dynamic/lessons/wenC6hgETeMHSiFNabvk`
`http://localhost:3000/courses/[language]/dynamic/lessons/[lessonID]`

I am trying to find an easy way to reach the following `.../exercises` page. All I need to do is add `/exercises` to the end of the above url. However, the following solution didn't work. Evidently, `<Link />` no longer remembers what the `[language]` or `[lessonID]` params are on my current page.

```
<Link href={`exercises/flashcards`} passHref>
   <a>begin</a>
</Link>
```

error message:
[image: screenshot of error message]

At this moment, the only solution I can think of is rewriting the entire URL with the needed slugs and passing that into `href`, but that feels a bit unnecessary if all I need to do is concat what I *already have* with `/exercises/flashcards`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to pass the params down as props, you can use `useRouter` to get the current path then add the extra bits to it in the `Link`'s href.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function SomePage() {
    const { asPath } = useRouter();

    return (
        <Link href={`${asPath}/exercises/flashcards`}>
            <a>begin</a>
        </Link>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the event that nobody answers, here is the solution **using my current slugs**.

```js
// using this nextjs function to pass the params of my url as a prop for SSR.
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  const { language, lessonID } = params;
  const data = await fetchLesson(language, lessonID);

  if (!data) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { data, params }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
}

---

// using those above param props within this Link on my component.
<Link
   href={`/courses/${props.params.language}/dynamic/lessons/${props.params.lessonID}/exercises/flashcards`}
   passHref
>
  <a>begin</a>
</Link>
```